# Merge columns into one while dropping nan values and duplicates

Tags: python, merge, multiple-columns

I am trying to merge multiple columns into a single column while dropping duplicates and dropping null values but keeping the rows.
What I have:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(np.array([['nan', 'nan', 'nan'], ['nan', 2, 2], ['nan', 'x', 'nan']]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

What I need:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(np.array([[''], [ 2], [ 1]]), columns=['a'])
```

I have tried this but I get 1,nan for the last row:

```
df['a]=df[['a','b','c]].agg(', '.join, axis=1)
```

I have also tried the following but I cannot get this to work:

```
.stack().unstack()
```

and

```
.join
```

but I cannot get these to drop duplicates for each row

Comment: `df.fillna('').stack().drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)`? Or are you looking to drop duplicates row-wise?

Comment: Good question Chris, I would like to drop duplicates row wise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find the maximum value of a row and replace 'nan' with `''`:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.astype(float).max(axis=1).replace(np.nan, ''), columns=[df.columns[0]])
```

output:

```
     a
0  
1  2.0
2  1.0
```